# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. Proposed solution isn't any good

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

with this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Name, t1.[value] AS DateTime
FROM 
    BmaCare.Questionnaire qu
LEFT JOIN 
    BmaCare.Pregnancy pr ON qu.PregnancyId = pr.Id
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(qu.Data, '$.actions')
        WITH (
             entries NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.entries' AS JSON) j
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(j.entries)
        WITH (
              [key] NVARCHAR(100) '$.key',
              [value] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value') t1
WHERE
    t1.[key] = 'Admission.DateTime' OR t1.[key] = 'Discharge.DateTime' 
    AND t1.[value] IS NOT NULL
    AND pr.Uuid = '50E8835B-4ECE-4333-9B5B-DD6AF611989C'
ORDER BY 
    DateTime DESC
```

A solution for this has been given here: [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792631/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-if-this-statement-is-a-common-table-ex)  which amounts to preceding every WITH by a semicolon. Very simple. When I do so in my SQL string, I get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

What do I do to get the query working?

Comment: i feel like you're running this against an older version of SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not when using `OPENJSON` ([Example 4 - Combine relational rows and JSON elements with CROSS APPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#example-4---combine-relational-rows-and-json-elements-with-cross-apply)). I would guess the OP isn't using SQL Server 2016+, as the others have.

Comment: I use SQL Server 2017 - so that's not it. Should 've mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Your database must be in compatibility level 130 (SQL Server 2016) or above in order to use `OPENJSON`. Otherwise, you will get a syntax error indicating the misplace `WITH` statement.

Comment: It is. I use SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @Cooz, are you certain your database compatibility level is 130 or 140? Verify with `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID();`. I get the same error when I try to run your script in a lower compatibility level but it parses successfully in 140.

Comment: The compatibility level is 140.

Comment: @Cooz, I successfully ran the exact query in your question after creating the tables with the columns referenced in the query. The only cause I can think of is that your are running the query in a database other than the one that returned the 140 compatibility level.